# Boost property tree: Remove a nested node

Tags: c++, boost, boost-propertytree

Suppose I have the following tree:

```
boost::property_tree::ptree tree;
tree.add("1.2.3", "value-1");
tree.add("1.2.3.4", "nested-value");
tree.add("1.2.3", "value-2");
tree.add("1.2.33", "other-value");
```

which has the following serialized INFO form:

```
1
{
    2
    {
        3 value-1
        {
            4 nested-value
        }
        3 value-2
        33 other-value
    }
}
```

Is there a method to remove all nodes having a provided (possibly nested) path?
I.e.:

```
remove(tree, "1.2.3");
BOOST_ASSERT(!tree.get_optional<std::string>("1.2.3") && 
             !tree.get_child_optional("1.2.3"));
```

with the result INFO form:

```
1
{
    2
    {
        33 other-value
    }
}
```

Looking at ptree docs and source code I've found several methods to remove immediate children of a tree (nested children are not accounted). Also, there are several methods to get a subtree by it's full path (even if it is nested). But since there is no way to easily get node's parent, I could not combine all these to get what I need.

Is there any easy way to get what I need, possibly w/o the need to reimplement tree traversal?

Comment: take a look at boost::adjacency_list and boost::default_dfs_visitor - complex but more powerful than property_tree

Comment: Thanks, but I also need the ability to serialize/deserialize the tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it can be done. It would be kind-a ok in JSON, but with INFO subtree keys can be repeated at each level, making it important to traverse all of the tree

Perhaps this answer helps to get started: [How to iterate over XML structure in boost::property_tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14069505/how-to-iterate-over-xml-structure-in-boostproperty-tree/14069977#14069977)

Be **very careful** about iterating a tree that's being modified, though. You will want to double check the iterator invalidation rules in the documentation for `erase`

Comment: Could you please elaborate about what is different with JSON in context of the question? 
The tree in my example fails to serialize to JSON, but it is probably not because of nesting, but because of one node, having both a value and a subtree. If I remove, e.g., the code line to add the node 1.2.3.4, then the tree serializes perfectly in JSON.

Comment: I never said something about the nesting. Indeed, I said the repeated subkey was a problem in JSON, which is exactly the same problem that prevents you doing a single `get_child_optional` + `erase`. The "extra feature" compounds, because you'll have to check for multi-valued keys _on every level_ (`1.2` might be repeated just as well)

Comment: It's possible to get, e.g., the following JSON with ptree serializer: { "1": { "2": { "3": "value-1" }, "2": "value-1" } } , which have a repeated subkey. Is it invalid JSON?

Comment: @AlexChe How is that relevant? It's invalid JSON according to [RFC4627](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt): ***`"The names within an object SHOULD be unique"`***. RFC2119 explains: _`"SHOULD   This word, or the adjective "RECOMMENDED", mean that there
   may exist valid reasons in particular circumstances to ignore a
   particular item, but the full implications must be understood and
   carefully weighed before choosing a different course"`_

Comment: Now I think I see your point. RFC recommends for JSON that all direct subkeys must be unique. Without this uniqueness we cannot be sure, that the node returned by the `get_child_optional` is the exact parent that contains the child node we want to delete. Actually, you've written this in your answer, but I was confused and distracted by JSON mention, since I considered storage format not related to the question. (I've provided INFO form only as visuals in my question.)

Comment: The backends all support slightly different feature sets, unfortunately. JSON arrays are also represented in quite a funny way :(

Answer (score 1):

In case someone needs it, here is how I done it (sorry, no C++11):

```
template <typename TTree>
boost::optional<TTree&> get_parent_optional(TTree& tree, 
                                            typename TTree::path_type path)
{
   if (path.empty())
      return boost::optional<TTree&>();

   TTree::key_type root = path.reduce();

   if (path.empty())
   {
      return (tree.find(root) != tree.not_found()) ? 
         boost::optional<TTree&>(tree) : boost::optional<TTree&>(); 
   }

   std::pair<TTree::assoc_iterator, TTree::assoc_iterator> range = 
      tree.equal_range(root);

   for (TTree::assoc_iterator it = range.first; it != range.second; ++it)
   {
      boost::optional<TTree&> result = get_parent_optional(it->second, path);
      if (result)
         return result;
   }

   return boost::optional<TTree&>();
}

template <typename TTree>
boost::optional<TTree&> get_parent_optional(TTree& tree, 
                                            const typename TTree::key_type & path)
{
   return get_parent_optional(tree, TTree::path_type(path));
}

template <typename TTree>
boost::optional<TTree&> get_parent_optional(TTree& tree, 
                                            const char * path)
{
   return get_parent_optional(tree, std::string(path));
}

template <typename TTree>
typename TTree::key_type get_last_fragment(const typename TTree::key_type & keyPath)
{
   TTree::path_type path(keyPath);

   if (path.empty())
      return TTree::key_type(); // or exception

   while (!path.single())
      path.reduce();

   return path.reduce();
}

template <typename TTree>
void erase(TTree & tree, const typename TTree::key_type & path)
{
   boost::optional<TTree&> parent;
   typename TTree::key_type subkey = get_last_fragment<TTree>(path);
   while (parent = get_parent_optional(tree, path))
   {
      parent->erase(subkey);
   }
}
```

Note, that in case there are several branches to delete, a tree is reiterated after every branch deletion. It could be a problem in case of a large tree.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by Alex Che's answer, here is my solution.  It assumes no repeated keys, and no keys containing both data and child nodes.  It returns a bool indicating success.  It also optionally removes parent keys that are empty, instead of leaving an empty value for the key.

`template <typename PTree>
bool erasePath(PTree &inout_tree, 
               const typename PTree::key_type &in_keyPath, 
               bool in_removeEmptyKeys)
{
    try
    {
        PTree *subTree = &inout_tree;
        typename PTree::path_type path(in_keyPath);
        typename PTree::key_type parentPath;
        typename PTree::key_type subKey;
        while (!path.single())
        {
            subKey = path.reduce();
            parentPath = parentPath.empty() ? subKey :
                parentPath + path.separator() + subKey;
            subTree = &(subTree->get_child(subKey));
        }
        subKey = path.reduce();
        if ( subTree->erase(subKey) == 0 )
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (in_removeEmptyKeys && subTree->empty() && !parentPath.empty())
        {
            return erasePath(inout_tree, parentPath);
        }
        return true;
    }
    catch (std::exception &)
    {
        return false;
    }
}`